# KAFKA consumer group disappeared

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are consuming records from KAFKA using java API periodically(say 1hr). Recently we noticed, subscribed consumer group was disappeared/deleted due to this our application is not getting any more messages from respective topic.

Is any one faced similar issue where KAFKA consumer group auto disappeared.

Comment: What´s the retention time on your __consumer_offsets topic?

Comment: retention.ms is not configured on this  __consumer_offsets topic so default is 7 days

Comment: Does your consumer group actually commit any offsets? Does the topic have all its ISRs and is otherwise healthy?

Comment: yes, it commits offset